# php exec not working with pdfinfo

Tags: php, exec

```
$cmd = "pdfinfo"; // Linux
            exec ( "$cmd \"$uploaddir_path.$list_files_upload[$list_files_upload_count] \"", $output );

        // Iterate through lines
        //$pagecount [$list_files_upload_count]= 0;
        foreach ( $output as $op ) {
            // Extract the number
            if (preg_match ( "/Pages:\s*(\d+)/i", $op, $matches ) === 1) {
                $pagecount [$list_files_upload_count] = intval ( $matches [1] );
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on linux plate form.

```
shell_exec()
```

is alternative of `exec()`

`exec()` is used in window and `shell_exec()` used on Linux platform.

[Read More](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

Comment: @divya can you let me know your OS plate form ?
Also make sure .. command execution (shell execution ) module enable from your Apache settings .

Comment: ubuntu..how tocheck apache settings in ubuntu

Comment: http://www.ozonesolutions.com/programming/2011/09/execute-php-5-script-command-line-ubuntu-linux/

This will may be helpful for you

Comment: please send me value of $uploaddir_path.$list_files_upload[$list_files_upload_count]

Comment: $cmd = " pdfinfo /home/ankit/demo.pdf ";
var_dump(shell_exec($cmd));

This has worked for me on ubuntu 14.05

Comment: test.pdf  is the value of uploaded file

Comment: from the php script you need to give full path 
like
/var/*
/home/*

protocols url will not work in this case.

please send me your command which is not working in your case

Comment: // Executing pdfinfo
   $cmd = "pdfinfo"; // Linux
   exec ( "$cmd \"$uploaddir_path.$list_files_upload[$list_files_upload_count] \"", $output );
   
   // Iterate through lines
   //$pagecount [$list_files_upload_count]= 0;
   foreach ( $output as $op ) {
    // Extract the number
    if (preg_match ( "/Pages:\s*(\d+)/i", $op, $matches ) === 1) {
     $pagecount [$list_files_upload_count] = intval ( $matches [1] );
     break;
    }
   }

Comment: $cmd ='/usr/bin/pdfinfo'; // Linux
 $tem_dir = '/var/www/myproject/upload/';

Comment: First thing please change
exec to shell_exec 

Second
You don't need to give full path of pdinfo 

Third 
Please give relative path of *.PDF file

Comment: Great .. Now you can close this topic just click on "Right" icon on left side of the Answer ! 

Thanks